# Image path from dynamic fields not uploaded in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am able to upload all other field values but not images.

My View:

**Hobby 1**

```
<input name="hobby[]" placeholder="Hobby1" type="text">
<input type="file" name="hobby_img[]">
<button>Add New Hobby</button>
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request, Hobby $hobbies)
for ($i=0; $i < count(request('hobby')); ++$i) 
        {
        $hobbies = new Hobby;
        $hobbies->hobby = request('hobby')[$i];

        $images = $request->file('hobby_img');
        $hob_img = uniqid() . '.' .$images[$key]->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $images[$i]->move(public_path('/assets/images/'), $hob_img);
        $hobbies->hobby_img = $hobby_img[$i];
        $hobbies->save();
        }
```

But it says

> The file xxxx.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown
>   error.

Comment: What's the code of your form tag?
 Have you added the "enctype='multipart/form-data'" attribute?
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Yes obviously. My form code ` <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{ route('add_hobbies') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" method="post" files="true">`